# C++ Networking: Request method POST

Tags: c++, http, networking, request

I'm trying to communicate with some server. To get username (with permissions), I need to do something like registration: HTTP request method POST send json-like body containing {"devicetype": "devicename"}. O tried to do it with ASIO library.

```
asio::error_code ec;
asio::io_context context;
asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("ipAddress", ec), 80);
asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);
if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Succesfully connected\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to address: \n" << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
if (socket.is_open())
    {
std::string sRequest =
            "POST /api HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host: ipAddress \r\n"
            "Body: {\"devicetype\": \"devicename\"}"
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
socket.write_some(asio::buffer(sRequest.data(), sRequest.size()), ec);

/*Reading received message and getting error message from server*/
}
```

Error says: "invalid/missing parameters in body". The parameters are correct. The problem is probably with message formatting I am sending (sRequest). How can I specify json body to message?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is not a properly formatted HTTP request. There is no `Body` header in HTTP. The JSON data needs to go after the `\r\n\r\n` that terminates the headers. And you need to add `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers so the server knows what kind of data you are posting and how large it is.

Try this instead:

```cpp
std::string json = "{\"devicetype\": \"devicename\"}";
std::string sRequest =
            "POST /api HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host: ipAddress\r\n"
            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
            "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(json.size()) + "\r\n"
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n" + json;
```